# Cannot set 100% height of div as height resets to 0px

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the div height of the separate parent columns (and their children) to 100% but it doesn't seem to be working because the div height mysteriously just resets to 0.

The **first column** has two child boxes (if I'm describing it correctly) which would take 50% (separately) of the page height. The **second and third** have one child box each which would both take 100% of the page height.

In addition to this I want to add a place holder for the logo on the top left of the page and a footer at the bottom of the page. With all of the above it seems a bit daunting. Would appreciate your advice.

In the end it should look like this:

[image]

I've uploaded it here: http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/qtmJW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `height: 100%;` on `#wrapper`

**Note** : Also remove `overflow: hidden;` from `#wrapper`

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtmJW/4/)

Edit : [**New Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtmJW/17/)

Comment: It works we. Same issue with @SpaceBeers there seems no footer. How do I go about setting this up along with the logo placeholder?

Comment: You can check this out, just remove `overflow: hidden;` from `#wrapper`